# PHP, No such file or directory

Tags: php

My php code show and error and i really don't know how to fix it.

```
Warning: file_put_contents(/ecc/.htpasswd): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /storage/ssd4/683/2921683/public_html/admin/htpasswd.php on line 19
```

[image: But the file actualy exist]

My code :

```
<?php
require('assets/head.php');
if ($_POST['perm'] == 0) {
    $dir = '/ecc/.htpasswd';
}
else {
    $dir = '.htpasswd';
    }
$user = strtoupper($_POST['grade']).strtoupper($_POST['nfamille']);
$nom = $_POST['nfamille'].' '.$_POST['pnom'];
// Password to be encrypted for a .htpasswd file
$clearTextPassword = $_POST['mdp'];
$ligne = count(file('.htpasswd')) + 1;
// Encrypt password
$password = crypt($clearTextPassword, base64_encode($clearTextPassword));

$file = $user.':'.$password."\n";
echo $file;
file_put_contents($dir, $file,FILE_APPEND);
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO CCPC(ligne, grade, nom, perm, prefix) 
VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
$req->execute(array($ligne, $_POST['grade'], $nom, $_POST['perm'], $user,));
?>
```

Thanks for the help
EDIT: Forgot to said that my php file is in the admin folder

Comment: That error also happens when it has no access to read it. Check the permissions, and ownerships.

Comment: @Randall That is not correct, you get a different error message in that case: permission denied

Comment: The path `"/ecc/.htpasswd"` starts at the file system's root. Not at your public_html folder. You should use the full path for `file_put_contents()`.

Comment: `/ecc/.htpasswd` means that it looks for the file in a folder called `/ecc` in the top level of the file system. Try with `/public_html/ecc/.htpasswd` or if the PHP file is in the same folder as the `ecc`-folder: `$dir = __DIR__ . '/ecc/.htpasswd`

Comment: i just undo that

Comment: @TheGamecraft: one does not store a password in a file or in a database. Also not in "encrypted" form. One stores a _hash_ of a password. Then, on authentication time, one again hashes the provided password and compare the two hashes.

Comment: @arkascha hm? Our server has thrown this error specifically when trying to deal with a file that had its permissions as '0' in regards to apache's user.group. As in, it couldnt see the file at all, so it threw the error of the file did not exist. Hmm. Either way, looks like THIS error is reference to wrong path entirely.

Comment: @Randall not sure what you actually saw, I have not been there, sure. However if the process trying to access a file does not have access it get's a "permission denied", certainly _not_ a "file does not exist". That might certainly be the case if a containing _folder_ does not have read or enter permission. But that is something else.

Answer (score 0):

Change `/ecc/.htpasswd` to `../ecc/.htpasswd`

Comment: does it say access denied now?